# A filesystem-based compression cache -- does this exist?

Tags: caching, compression, filesystems, http-compression

I'm looking for a program with really quite specific functionality, which hopefully exists so I don't have to implement it myself.  I can best describe this hypothetical program as a filesystem-based cache of compressed copies of documents in the working directory.  I've made a mock-up of what I would expect this program to do:

```
james@pc:~/htdocs/$ tree -a
.
|-- image.png
`-- index.html

0 directories, 2 files

james@pc:~/htdocs/$ zipcache init
Initialized cache in ./.zipcache/
james@pc:~/htdocs/$ tree -a
.
|-- .zipcache
|   |-- gzip
|   |   `-- index.html.gz
|   `-- lzma
|       `-- index.html.lzma
|-- image.png
`-- index.html

1 directory, 3 files
james@pc:~/htdocs/$ zipcache gzip index.html
... zipcache emits gzipped copy of index.html on stdout by cat-ing ./.zipcache/gzip/index.html.gz
james@pc:~/htdocs/$ zipcache lzma index.html
... zipcache emits lzma'd copy of index.html on stdout by cat-ing ./.zipcache/lzma/index.html.gz
james@pc:~/htdocs/$ zipcache lzma image.png
... zipcache generates error signifying cache miss (it's intelligent enough to know that PNG shouldn't be further zipped) ...
```

My ultimate concern is caching compressed copies of static files that are repeatedly transferred over HTTP with Content-encoding enabled.  I have no desire to calculate compression every time a file is requested.

I would still appreciate pointing in the right direction if something vaguely similar to the above exists -- my Google searching has been quite unsuccessful (perhaps there is terminology for the above functionality that I don't know about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Admittedly, this is answering the "one up from this" question instead]

It seems like doing this yourself is a bad idea and you should let the web server do this.

I'm guessing you're using apache on a unix variant, but for completeness:

- For IIS7, you can just configure it since it supports caching of compressed static (and dynamic) content - see http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression
- For Apache, I can't find anything as built-in, but mod_deflate and mod_disk_cache seem like where you want to start.  Check out http://webdirect.no/linux/apache-caching-with-gzip-enabled/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can write quite simple PHP script for such caching. I am not sure such thing exists already